# If statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I would like to use an if statement in a MySQL query to `SELECT` all of the information in a database where... if it returns true, or return the `COUNT` of the column named `aid`.

Pseudocode:

```
IF (COUNT(`AID`) > 0) {
  SELECT * FROM `a_votes` WHERE `aid` = '1'
} ELSE {
  RETURN 'No Rows'
}
```

Please could you tell me how I could do this?

Edit---

I tried the following query, but I am receiving the error `Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

```
SELECT IF( (

SELECT COUNT( aid ) AS  `count` 
FROM  `a_votes` 
WHERE  `aid` =1 ) =0,  'true', (

    SELECT * 
    FROM  `a_votes` 
    WHERE  `aid` =1
  )

) AS message
```

Comment: Where would you use the result? How would you know which branch executed?

Comment: I would know as the query would either return the count or it would return the relevant rows from the table `a_votes`

Comment: Hmmm, if `COUNT(AID) == 0` then there is no point in returning the second query. Isn't it better just to return zero rows?

Comment: Surely if it ever reaches the else statement, it'll return 0 - so why are you counting again at that point?

Comment: That's correct, I will update the question.

Comment: MySQL has to know the structure of the result: this means that your result must have the same number of columns, whichever branch of the `IF` is chosen.

Comment: BTW, how many rows should the `... WHERE aid=1` query match? Exactly 1, 0..1, 0..N, 1..N ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as COUNT FROM a_votes WHERE aid = '1'
) x WHERE COUNT > 0;
```

If no rows match, a simple `COUNT(*))` will returns a single row with `0` for the count. Wrapping the usual `COUNT(*)` query in an outer query that eliminates that condition will return no rows.

#### Edited:

Thanks to [`@bisiclop`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/260007/biziclop), this is a better solution:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as COUNT
FROM a_votes
WHERE aid = '1'
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0;
```

Comment: Don't forget to rename `COUNT` to something else (not the function, but the given name), or wrap it into doublequotes. How your query will return `SELECT * FROM a_votes` when needed? Couldn't your query be rewritten as `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... HAVING COUNT(*)>0` ?

Comment: @biziclop You're right: `HAVING` will do it! (I can't believe I didn't see that)

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to transcribe your pseudocode to SQL, this would be the result, but I think it is unnecessarily complex, so it is just a demonstration:

```
/* this query might return zero rows, so beware */
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(`aid`) > 0 FROM `a_votes`) AS the_count,
  the_row.*
FROM
  (SELECT * FROM `a_votes` WHERE `aid` = '1') AS the_row
```

The same using `LEFT JOIN`, it must return at least one row:

```
SELECT *
/* count will create exactly 1 row */
FROM      (SELECT COUNT(`aid`) > 0 FROM `a_votes`)    AS the_count
/* this is allowed to return 0,1,...N rows */
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM `a_votes` WHERE `aid` = '1') AS the_row
```

Comment: How to write this SQL query if I want to condition for GREATER THEN or LESS THEN?

Comment: I added ` > 0`, if you meant that.